# Format int as int, but float as %.3f

Tags: python, string-formatting, python-2.5

I have a function that expects two cutoff values, called `min_df` and `max_df`. Either may be an `int` to denote an absolute frequency cutoff, or a `float` to denote a relative frequency. Now, I want to add some checks and give appropriate warning messages, but without too much clutter. This works:

```
if max_df < 0 or min_df < 0:
    raise ValueError, "neither max_df (%s) nor min_df (%s) may be <0" %
                      (max_df, min_df)
```

but with a `float` such as `(1/3.)`, the warning contains `0.333333333333`. I'd rather have it say `0.333`, so I tried `%.3f`, but that turns `int` values into floats as well and displays `2.000` for `2`.

How do I switch on type to get the right format? Do I need to build the format string before passing it to the `%` operator?

**Update**: I need something that works in Python 2.5, since that's the minimum version I'm targeting.

Comment: Deciding between absolute and relative based on numeric type sounds like something that would violate the principle of least astonishment. I'd use a boolean keyword argument `relative=False` or something else instead.

Comment: The problem is that there are two cutoff parameters that work in this way, and more may be implemented, so I'd need to double the number of parameters.

Comment: I think @grep's method is the way to go, but you could do something tricky with nested specifiers on a newer version of Python -- `int_fl = lambda num: '' if isinstance(num, int) else '.3f'` then
`print "Neither max_df ({:{}}) nor min_df ({:{}}) may be negative.".format(max_df, int_fl(max_df), min_df, int_fl(min_df))`

Comment: @larsmans: Then how about a couple of thin wrapper classes? So you'd call it like `foo(Absolute(1), Relative(2), Absolute(3))`. You could then move the cutoff logic into them and use polymorphism rather than explicit dispatch on the argument types.

Comment: I agree you shouldn't use type to distinguish -- You could subclass `int` and `float` and add a class attribute `relative = False` and `relative = True` respectively, so you can tell them apart with `if max_df.relative`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep it simple

```
def format_df(df):
    if isinstance(df, (int, long)):
        return "%d" % df
    elif isinstance(df, float):
        return "%.3f" % df
    else:
        return str(df) # fallback just in case

raise ValueError, "neither max_df (%s) nor min_df (%s) may be <0" %
                  (format_df(max_df), format_df(min_df))
```

Answer (score 6):

How about this:

```
>>> "{:.4g}".format(1)
'1'
>>> "{:.4g}".format(1.3)
'1.3'
>>> "{:.4g}".format(1.333)
'1.333'
>>> "{:.4g}".format(1.333333)
'1.333'
```

However (since the 4 significant digits also include the integer part) you'd also get this:

```
>>> "{:.4g}".format(10.333)
'10.33'
>>> "{:.4g}".format(10000)
'1e+04'
```

Comment: The `g` specifier would be nice if it didn't show `1.` as `1`. The difference between `int` and `float` is crucial.